# For and if loop combination takes lot of time in Pandas (Data manipulation)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-manipulation

I have two datasets, each about half a million observations. I am writing the below code and it seems the code never seems to stop executing. I would like to know if there is a better way of doing it. Appreciate inputs.

Below are sample formats of my dataframes. Both dataframes share a set of 'sid' values , meaning all the 'sid' values in 'df2' will have a match in 'df1' 'sid' values. The 'tid' values and consequently the 'rid' values (which are a combination of 'sid' and 'tid' values) may not appear in both sets.

The task is simple. I would like to create the 'tv' column in df2. Wherever the 'rid' in df2 matches with the 'rid' in 'df1', the 'tv' column in df2 takes the corresponding 'tv' value from df1. If it does not match, the 'tv' value in 'df2' will be the median 'tv' value for the matching 'sid' subset in 'df1'.

In fact my original task includes creating a few more similar columns like 'tv' in df2 (based on their values in 'df1' ; these columns exist in 'df1').

I believe as my code contains for loop combined with if else statement and multiple value assignment statements, it is taking forever to execute. Appreciate any inputs.

```
df1
    sid     tid     rid     tv
0   0       0       0-0     9
1   0       1       0-1     8
2   0       3       0-3     4
3   1       5       1-5     2
4   1       7       1-7     3
5   1       9       1-9     14
6   1       10      1-10    24
7   1       11      1-11    13
8   2       14      2-14    2
9   2       16      2-16    5
10  3       17      3-17    6
11  3       18      3-18    8
12  3       20      3-20    5
13  3       21      3-21    11
14  4       23      4-23    6


df2
    sid     tid     rid
0   0       0       0-0
1   0       2       0-2
2   1       3       1-3
3   1       6       1-6
4   1       9       1-9
5   2       10      2-10
6   2       12      2-12
7   3       1       3-1
8   3       15      3-15
9   3       1       3-1
10  4       19      4-19
11  4       22      4-22

rids = [rid.split('-') for rid in df1.rid]

for r in df2.rid:
    s,t = r.split('-')
    if [s,t] in rids:
        df2.loc[df2.rid== r,'tv'] = df1.loc[df1.rid == r,'tv']
    else:
        df2.loc[df2.rid== r,'tv'] = df1.loc[df1.sid == int(s),'tv'].median()
```

The expected df2 shall be as follows:

```
    sid     tid     rid     tv
0   0       0       0-0     9.0
1   0       2       0-2     8.0
2   1       3       1-3     13.0
3   1       6       1-6     13.0
4   1       9       1-9     14.0
5   2       10      2-10    3.5
6   2       12      2-12    3.5
7   3       1       3-1     7.0
8   3       15      3-15    7.0
9   3       1       3-1     7.0
10  4       19      4-19    6.0
11  4       22      4-22    6.0
```

Comment: can you post your expected outputfrom the sample dataframe?

Comment: Added the expected output dataframe to the original post.

Comment: As a tip, if you were to post your actual code, you would receive more help.

Comment: got it updated answer..kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can left merge on df2 with a subset(because you need only tv column you can also pass the df1 without any subset) of df1 on 'rid' then calculate median and fill values:

```
out=df2.merge(df1[['rid','tv']],on='rid',how='left')
out['tv']=out['tv_y'].fillna(out['sid'].map(df1.groupby('sid')['tv'].median()))
out= out.drop(['tv_x','tid_y','tv_y'], axis=1)
out = out.rename(columns = {'tid_x': 'tid'})
out
```

**OR**

Since you said that:

all the 'sid' values in 'df2' will have a match in 'df1' 'sid' values

So you can also left merge them on `['sid','rid']` and then `fillna()` value of tv with the median of df1 'tv' column by mapping values using `map()` method:

```
out=df2.merge(df1,on=['sid','rid'],how='left')
out['tv']=out['tv_y'].fillna(out['sid'].map(df1.groupby('sid')['tv'].median()))
out= out.drop(['tv_x','tv_y'], axis=1)
out
```

output of out:

```
    sid     tid     rid     tv
0   0       0       0-0     9.0
1   0       2       0-2     8.0
2   1       3       1-3     13.0
3   1       6       1-6     13.0
4   1       9       1-9     14.0
5   2       10      2-10    3.5
6   2       12      2-12    3.5
7   3       1       3-1     7.0
8   3       15      3-15    7.0
9   3       1       3-1     7.0
10  4       19      4-19    6.0
11  4       22      4-22    6.0
```

Comment: Thanks. The above solutions work. But, I guess there are couple of minor errors in the above code. the second line in both options got to be out['tv']=out['tv_y'].fillna(out['sid'].map(df1.groupby('sid')['tv'].median())). Then, the additional,unrequired columns createdduring merge shall be dropped to get to the required answer.

Comment: I made those changes to your code. Thanks.

Comment: @Srinivas Glad it helped..happy coding **:)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion without any loops, based on dictionaries:

```
matching_values = dict(zip(df1['rid'][df1['rid'].isin(df2['rid'])], df1['tv'][df1['rid'].isin(df2['rid'])]))

df2[df2['rid'].isin(df1['rid'])]['tv'] = df2[df2['rid'].isin(df1['rid'])]['rid']

df2[df2['rid'].isin(df1['rid'])]['tv'].replace(matching_values)


median_values = df2[(~df2['rid'].isin(df1['rid']) & (df2['sid'].isin(df1['sid'])].groupby('sid')['tv'].median().to_dict() 

df2[(~df2['rid'].isin(df1['rid']) & (df2['sid'].isin(df1['sid'])]['tv'] = df2[(~df2['rid'].isin(df1['rid']) & (df2['sid'].isin(df1['sid'])]['sid']

df2[(~df2['rid'].isin(df1['rid']) & (df2['sid'].isin(df1['sid'])]['tv'].replace(median_values)
```

This should do the trick. The logic here is that we first create a dictionary, in which the "rid and "sid" values are the keys and the median and matching "tv" values are the dictionary values. Next, we replace the "tv" values in df2 with the rid and sid keys, respectively, (because they are the dictionary keys) which can thus easily be replaced by the correct tv values by calling `.replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use for loops in pandas, that is known to be slow. That way you don't get to benefit from all the internal optimizations that have been made.

Try to use the split-apply-combine pattern:

- split df1 into sid to calculate the median: `df1.groupby('sid')['tv'].median()`
- join df2 on df1: `df2.join(df1.set_index('rid'), on='rid')`
- fill the NaN values with the median calculated in step 1.

(Haven't tested the code).